# Не работаю стили при запуске сервера на node.js

Tags: node.js, express

Прошу помощи. Писали стили для странички, писал без запущенного сервера, все работало прекрасно. Решил проверить как это будет функционировать при запущенном сервере, запустил и увидел что стили не отображаются от слова совсем. Почитал про обработку статических файлов в Express, немного пофиксил код, но это ситуацию не поменяло. В чем может быть проблема?

```js
// Подключаем все необходимые пакеты
const express = require('express')
const basicAuth = require('basic-auth')
const app = express()

// Функция для проверки логина и пароля
function checkUser(username, password) {
    if (username === 'dhelfy' && password === 'pass1235') {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

// Middleware для авторизации
function authMiddleWare(req, res, next) {
    // Создаем переменную куда положим реквизиты для входа из запроса
    let credentials = basicAuth(req)

    // Проверяем запрос на заполненность и проверяем реквизиты с помощью функции checkUser
    if (!credentials || !checkUser(credentials.name, credentials.pass)) {
        res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="This page requires authentication"')
        res.status(401).send('Anauthorized')
    } else {
        next()
    }
}

// Два обработчика запросов на два url
app.get('/index.html', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.get('/secured.html', authMiddleWare, function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/secured.html')
})

app.use(express.static('public'))

// Запуск сервера который будет слушать запросы на 3000 порту
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Сервер запущен на порту 3000')
})
```

```css
:root {
    --text: #e9ecec;
    --background: #101014;
    --primary: #480f89;
    --secondary: #2b2b77;
    --accent: #45a1d7;
    --linearPrimarySecondaryAccent: linear-gradient(90deg, #480f89, #2b2b77, #45a1d7);
}

* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: var(--text);
    font-family: "Poppins";
}

h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
}

button {
    background-color: var(--primary);
    height: 50px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    font-weight: 600;
}

button:active {
    background-color: var(--secondary);
}

.body {
    background-color: var(--background);
}

.centered-flex-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.main-content {
    width: max-content;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.gradient-italic {
    font-style: italic;
    background: var(--linearPrimarySecondaryAccent);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Start Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="body">
    <div class="centered-flex-container">    
        <main class="main-content">
            <h1>Hello! This is a <span class="gradient-italic">start page!</span></h1>
            <button class="login-button" onclick="location.href = 'secured.html'">Login</button>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: попробуйте `public` из пути стилей убрать

Comment: @Arbery для чего? Они действительно лежат в директории public

Comment: @Arbery к слову попробовал, ребутнул сервер и это сработало. Немного почитав, сам выяснил, что при указании экспрессу из какой директории брать статически файлы не нужно дополнительно прописывать имя этой директории при указании пути до файла в том же HTML. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Немного почитав, сам выяснил, что при указании в Express из какой директории брать статически файлы не нужно дополнительно прописывать имя этой директории при указании пути до файла в том же HTML.

В моем случае мы указываем имя директории здесь `app.use(express.static('public'))` и его не нужно указывать в пути до .css файла повторно при подключении. Поэтому верный путь будет таким: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">`, вместо `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/style.css">`. Большая благодарность @Arbery